# How do payroll-deducted taxes get sent to the IRS?

Tags: united-states, taxes, payroll-taxes

What do employers do with the money they've withheld from you before they get sent in? Where do they deposit it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The money gets sent to the IRS through the [EFTPS](https://www.eftps.gov/eftps/) system. Depending on the amounts, the employers are required to deposit it on a [monthly/semi-weekly basis](https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Depositing-and-Reporting-Employment-Taxes), so they don't get to keep the tax money for long.

Failure to deposit the payroll taxes on time is one of the most heavily penalized IRS offenses. This area of violations is called "[trust fund violations](https://www.hg.org/article.asp?id=24859)". It is one of the very few areas in which **employees** may be liable for corporate misdoings (i.e.: an HR or accounting manager responsible for payroll may be personally liable for trust fund violations).

Comment: There are similar systems and requirements for other federal and state deductions.

Comment: For most, if not all, corporate tax remittance EFTPS would be a requirement, but the heavy penalties and personal liability is quite unusual. States impose similar requirements re their payroll taxes as well.

Comment: Do keep in mind that this applies to individuals as well.  If you have substantial income that is not subject to withholding, you are required to submit quarterly estimates.  Further, if your end-of-year final payment is > (IIRC) 10% of your total tax bill, you will be fined for failing to submit proper estimates.

Comment: @Perkins I don't doubt it, but what makes it so bad not paying taxes for employees is that it isn't your money, it's the employees' money, making it something very similar to theft. So it's worse than not paying company taxes (which is _your_ money), or your own taxes (which is _your_ money).

Comment: @Perkins: It's $1000 in taxes, https://www.irs.gov/Businesses/Small-Businesses-&-Self-Employed/Estimated-Taxes

Comment: @Perkins penalties for underpayment for individuals are ridiculous comparing to the penalties for trust fund violations (which may end up being more than the trust fund amount itself + criminal charges). In fact, they're so low that some people consider it cheaper than taking a loan from a bank and postpone their tax estimate payments to the end of the year. Higher penalties are for failure **to file** where you don't file the tax return on time when you owe taxes, but even that not as high as the penalties for trust fund violations.

Comment: "one of the very few areas", well, only because businesses mostly avoid activities where their employees would be individually criminally liable. If your employer's business model was robbing banks with a shotgun, then *at least* those employees who perform the actual stickup would be liable, and potentially everyone for conspiracy. The IRS views payroll tax fraud (or even negligence) similarly.